Definition of orientable manifolds
We have the following two definitions of orientable manifolds:
(Algebraic Topology Munkres P383)Let $X$ be a compact triangulated homology $n$-manifold. We say that $X$ is orientable if it is possible to orient all the $n$-simplices $\sigma_i$ of $X$ so their sum $\gamma=\sum \sigma_i$ is a cycle. Such a cycle $\gamma$ will be called an orientation cycle for $X$.
(GTM94 P139)Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold of dimension $n$. Then the following are equivalent:
(a) $M$ is orientable.
(b) There is a collection $\Phi=\{(V, \psi)\}$ of coordinate systems on $M$ such that
$$
M=\bigcup_{(V, \psi) \in \Phi} V \quad \text { and } \quad \operatorname{det}\left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y_j}\right)>0 \quad \text { on } \quad U \cap V
$$
whenever $\left(U, x_1, \ldots, x_n\right)$ and $\left(V, y_1, \ldots, y_n\right)$ belong to $\Phi$.
(c) There is a nowhere-vanishing $n$-form on $M$.
I wonder that for compact differentiable manifold $M$(it's well-known that $M$ can be triangulated), how can these two definitions coincide?

I don't know how direct of a proof there is. One could show that both definitions are equivalent to the fact that the top homology group $H_n(X)$ does not vanish, but that takes a while.
